# adding image in richtextbox

Tags: c#, image, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextbox` I use as a log and to add something to it, I use the following code:

```
Font fontMsg = new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
txtLog.SelectionFont = fontMsg;
txtLog.SelectionColor = Color.MediumVioletRed;
txtLog.SelectedText = "Connection.HTTP: Failed to connect!";
txtLog.SelectedText = "\r\n";
```

This works perfectly, since it keeps appending to textbox and I don't need to deal with rfc code. Is it possible to add an image the same way without using the code? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `System.Windows.Forms.ListView` instead.

Comment: I'm thinking about it, but the log might be huge and listview seems to flicker a lot.